# Is the Safari version of the Xcode iOS simulator different from the iOS version?

Tags: ios, safari, webkit

What I found out through the Internet is that the iOS version rules and Safari's version rules are the same.

And I need to display the web using WebKit on iOS.

It was scheduled to be supported starting from iOS 14, but we confirmed that the [Private_class_fileds, Private_class_fileds, Static_class_fields] JavaScript syntax is properly supported starting from iOS 15.

So I did a test with iOS 15.

However, I ran iOS15 with the Xcode simulator, but the web did not respond.

I confirmed that iPhone 7 (iOS 15.6.1) is running on the actual terminal, but 15.6.1 is not available in the simulator.
I tested it with iPhone 7 (iOS 16.1) and it worked.

Does the Safari version of the Xcode simulator work differently than the iOS version?

Comment: It is called `simulator` so everything you see is just `simulate`-ing the actual apps and environment of the iOS. Although I have no proofs for that. ‍♂️